# Is this a vertical asymptote?

Tags: limits, functions

I have this function:

$$ f(x) = (x+1) \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}} $$

I have the two side limits:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^-} { (x+1) \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}} } = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} { (x+1) \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}} } = +\infty $$

So the right left side limit is not infinity. Is that still considered an asymptote?

Comment: Yes the $y$-axis is asymptotic to the curve of $f$ at $0^+$.

Comment: Suggestion: this is essentially a question of terminology (can this be called an asymptote). Should it receive the asymptote tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an asymptote exists at $\;\;x = 0$. An asymptote can exist even if a limit does not  approach infinity, as in the case here, where the function is asymptotic to the $x$ axis ($y = 0$) near the origin.

See the graph of $f(x) = (x + 1)\, e^{1/x}\,$ below, compliments of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20%28x%2b1%29%20*e%5E%281/x%29). The graph below is "zoomed in" near the origin. As $x \to 0^-$, $f(x) \to 0$, but never reaches zero. Hence, the function becomes horizontally asymptotic to $y = 0$.

[image]

Here is more "global" version of the graph of the same function, where you can see that the function is vertically asymptotic to $x = 0$ as $x\to 0^+$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if the limit doesn't tend to infinity it can still be an asymptote. In your example, an asymptote exists and is at $y=0$.